# A question on object oriented programming

Tags: javascript, class, attributes, javascript-objects, this

Good day developers.

I am working through a task on object oriented programming, I am given the following question,
where I am requested to create a class named
Shoes.
Within this class I have to create the following attributes:

■ Name

■ Product Code

■ Quantity

■ Value per item

● Then, create 5 instances of the Shoes class and push all to an array.

● The code should have the following methods that interact with the array:

○ A method to search for any shoe within the array.

○ A method to find the shoe with the lowest value per item.

○ A method to find the shoe with the highest value per item.

○ A method to edit any aspect of an instance of the shoes class.

○ A method to order all of the objects in ascending order.

● Keeping in mind that all of my outputs when running these methods should
be displayed in an easy to read, presentable manner.

I attempted it, but I think it is still missing some code.
I'd appreciate your input.

```
const instances = [];
        
class Shoes {
    //a constructor of the class
    constructor(Name, ProductCode, Quantity, ValuePerItem){
        //initiatilising attributes of the class, with the 'this' keyword, referring to the current object
        this.Name = Name;
        this.ProductCode = ProductCode;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
        this.ValuePerItem= ValuePerItem;
        this.displayCard = () =>{
           console.log(`${Name}  ${ProductCode}  ${Quantity}  ${ValuePerItem}`);
        };
        instances.push(this);
    };  //
    const includesShoe = instances.includes(Shoe);
    console.log(includesShoe);
        
    const min = Math.min(...instances);
    console.log(min);

    const max = Math.max(...instances); 
    console.log(max);

static Getshoes() {
    instances.forEach( x => {
        x.displayShoe();
    });
   }       
  }

new Shoes('Name', ProductCode, Quantity, ValuePerItem);
new Shoes('Name', ProductCode, Quantity, ValuePerItem);
    
instances[1].displayShoe();    
    
Shoes.Getshoes();
```

Comment: this assignment is vague and you better ask for clarifications.  "A method to search for any shoe" or "A method to edit any aspect of an instance" don't really make much sense.

Comment: i get what you mean, but i think it does make sense. we are required to create a method which we can use to search for any shoe within the array.